# Not able to show the alert if user denied the camera access

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, alert

If user dennied the camera access, i am showing one alert with cancel and setting button to show it. But the code is not working.

```
@IBAction func ProfileImageButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("profile image Button is pressed")
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        profileimgbool = true
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Photo Source", message: "choose a Source", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) in imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) in imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)}))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))



        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

 func checkCameraPermission()  {
        let cameraMediaType = AVMediaType.video
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: cameraMediaType) { granted in
            if granted {
                //Do operation
                print("Granted access for camera")
               // self.setCamera()
            } else {
                self.noCameraFound()
                print("Denied access for camera ")
            }
        }
    }
    func noCameraFound(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "CallDoc", message: "Please allow camera access in phone settings", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Back", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) in


        }));

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open setting", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) in
            UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

        }));
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

in my above code my method was `checkCameraPermission` where i will call this to show alert. I needs to show when user click camera, and when if user denied that black screen will show instead of camera. There i need to show that alert pop up.

Where i can call this `checkCameraPermission` method to show my popup ?.

Any idea ?

Comment: where you struck

Comment: are you checked this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646107/how-to-check-if-the-user-gave-permission-to-use-the-camera

Comment: see this for help also: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2018/02/24/swift-cheat-sheet-for-iphone-camera-access-usage/

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes after that only i wrote . not able to solve

Comment: what was the issue u faced.what the help u need

Comment: Can i able to add this code like this `actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) in
            let cameraAuthorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)
            
            switch cameraAuthorizationStatus {
            case .notDetermined: self.requestCameraPermission()
            case .authorized: self.presentCamera()
            case .restricted, .denied: self.alertCameraAccessNeeded()
            }
            
        }))`

Comment: inside the selection of action sheert

Comment: its wrong, actually you want to show the alert or else if user press the camera correct

Comment: yes ..if already they denied. i needs to show the alert

Comment: wait I will add the answer check once may be it will helpful

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for reference purpose I taken the answer from [this](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2018/02/24/swift-cheat-sheet-for-iphone-camera-access-usage/) tutorial.

**step 1**

add the avfoundation framework in your project

```
import AVFoundation
```

**step 2**

dont forget to Set Camera Usage Description in Info.plist

When you request permission to use the device’s camera, a short message will appear in the default iOS system dialog. You customize this message by adding the `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` key to your `Info.plist` file.

**step 3**

on your image profile change button action verify the permission, etc.

```
@IBAction func ProfileImageButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
 let cameraAuthorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)
  switch cameraAuthorizationStatus {
case .notDetermined: requestCameraPermission()
case .authorized: presentCamera()
case .restricted, .denied: alertCameraAccessNeeded()
}
}
```

based on the above action the condition will satisfy,

> If the user has never responded to a request to access his/her camera, you need to prompt with the iOS system alert to request permission:

```
 func requestCameraPermission() {
AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video, completionHandler: {accessGranted in
    guard accessGranted == true else { return }
    self.presentCamera()
})
}
```

there after the camera access will continue

```
 func presentCamera() {
let photoPicker = UIImagePickerController()
photoPicker.sourceType = .camera
photoPicker.delegate = self as? UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate

self.present(photoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

> To use the image that the camera captured, you need to set up your view controller to adhere to and implement couple of delegate protocols:

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
  // ...
 }

 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
let photo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
// do something with the photo... set to UIImageView, save it, etc.

dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If camera access has been denied or restricted, you can alert the user and direct them to the Settings app to make the appropriate permissions adjustment:

```
func alertCameraAccessNeeded() {
let settingsAppURL = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!

let alert = UIAlertController(
    title: "Need Camera Access",
    message: "Camera access is required to make full use of this app.",
    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert
)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Allow Camera", style: .cancel, handler: { (alert) -> Void in
    UIApplication.shared.open(settingsAppURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}))

present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: bro any help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54854118/how-to-pass-the-values-to-selected-pagemenu-title-vc