# NotificationCenter is not getting trigger in my obj c class ( utills class or object class ). Not an viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, nsnotificationcenter

I have one obj c class, swift file. And here is my code :

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)

#include "InterfaceManagerInstance.h"

void IOSInterfaceManager::testMethod() {}
void IOSInterfaceManager::initialize(){
}
std::string IOSInterfaceManager::getColorPrimary(){
    return "";
}


void IOSInterfaceManager::onOver(int nameID,int fameid, int nickNameID){

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"openBoard" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
            NSLog(@"Finished!");

        });

    }
```

`userInfo:userInfo` is my NSDictionary.

.h file code :

```
class IOSInterfaceManager : public InterfaceManager
{
public:
void onOver(int nameID,int fameid, int nickNameID);
};
```

Now in my swift file :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.openBoard(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("openBoard"), object: nil)
}

    @objc func openBoard(notification: Notification) {


    }
```

Now in my obj c class `NSLog(@"Finished!");` this is getting print in my console. But `openBoard` is not printing. Not sure what that the issue here. Any help would be useful.

Thanks in advance !

Update :

When i add breakpoint in my `NSNotificationCenter` i am getting this warning :

> warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data
>   in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information
>   available.

[image]

Comment: Check whether you are posting the notification before adding the observer.

Comment: Should work... just did a quick, very simple test without problems. Example code is here (`ViewController.swift`, `MyTestClass.h`, `MyTestClass.m`, `ProjName-Bridging-Header.h`) if you want to compare: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/a6fa54512b5fb0fb8a227b996f6ff93b

Comment: my code also look lis same righ ?

Comment: its look very same...but not sure why its not getting trigger...

Comment: @david - are you sure your Swift class (I'm assuming it's a `UIViewController` subclass?) has been instantiated and is in scope when the notification fires?

Comment: @ThEuSeFuL i checked its correct only. also updated the code with some warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.

Comment: is this possible to attach your project

Comment: Its an full project...but when i do as seperate project its working fine....

Comment: i have updated the full code only

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i updated my full code for ur referance

Comment: But ` NSLog(@"Finished!");` is getting printed in my console

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik   i created an sample project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e9_DTFL7RQY-3qtBcwTGG2uCmU3Gr8gu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  this is also not working

Comment: okay give the time I will check and let u know

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sure thanks u

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  any luck on that ?

Comment: I am not seen bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your sample project, the main problem is that you *never instantiate* the Swift `ViewController` class. So, the `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` code never runs, and the object doesn't exist to get the notification anyway.

In your `testLogin.m` class, you need to create a `ViewController` property, and instantiate the class. Make it a property and not a local variable so it doesn't go out of scope.

You also need to make a couple changes to your Swift class. Presumably, you intend to load this as a `UIViewController`, so you *could* leave the `.addObserver` line in `viewDidLoad()`, but... if you haven't yet done anything to actually load the view, that won't be called either. Better to implement the `init` methods and do it there.

In your sample project, replace `ViewController.swift` with:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  notificationCenter
//
//  Created by SATHISH on 3/1/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 sathish. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@objc class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        print("Swift ViewController class init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) was called.")
        setupNotif()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        print("Swift ViewController class init?(coder aDecoder) was called.")
        setupNotif()
    }

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        print("Swift ViewController class init() was called.")
        setupNotif()
    }

    func setupNotif() -> Void {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.openScoreBoard(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("openScoreBoard"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func openScoreBoard(notification: Notification) {
        print("Swift openScoreBoard(notification: Notification) was triggered!")
    }
}
```

and replace testLogin.m with this:

```
//
//  testLogin.m
//  notificationCenter
//
//  Created by SATHISH on 3/1/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 sathish. All rights reserved.
//

#import "testLogin.h"
#import "notificationCenter-Swift.h"

@interface testLogin ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *swiftVC;

@end

@implementation testLogin

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // instantiate an instance of the Swift ViewController
    _swiftVC = [ViewController new];

}

- (IBAction)clickedAction:(id)sender {

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"gameScore": @"123", @"gameID": @"123", @"gameSkillID": @"123"};
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"openScoreBoard" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
        NSLog(@"Finished!");
    });
}

@end
```

There are only a few changes -- if you compare your originals with these, the diffs will be obvious.

Comment: thanks for ur solution. But one small changes. I am using nsobjec class not view controller for obj c.. So i am getting some warning like `'NSObject' may not respond to 'viewDidLoad'` in my view did load method. How can i make initialize for nsobject class for `_swiftVC = [SocreBoardVC new];` ?

Comment: And when i do `@property (strong, nonatomic) VidwController *swiftVC;` it is mandatory to do like this `#import "notificationCenter-Swift.h"` bec when i do that i am getting some protocal, delage issue for google sign in inside `#import "notificationCenter-Swift.h"`.Attached screenshots too

Comment: but i used that delegate methods in my login vc already inside extensions

Comment: `_swiftVC = [SocreBoardVC new];` does not need to be in `viewDidLoad` ... it can be anywhere that you want to execute it. The problem was that you never instantiated the Swift class --- you had a Swift file in your project, and expected some magic to make it do something.

Comment: As to your next question -- *"cannot find protocol declaration for GIDSignInDelegate"* --  I can't possibly know that much about your code that I have never seen. And, that's an entirely different issue from what this question was about.